# a beginner trying out beamer, can't get it to itemize

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize

I can't get this to itemize, I just want a couple bullet points in my block sorry for the lengthy header its my professors lol

```
%A.DOCUMENTCLASSes.
%The document class produces a style for the document. %Most papers work fine with the next one.
%For letter style see the letter document on the website.
% For presentations, see a beamer document on the website. %
%\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\documentclass[blue]{beamer} 
%\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
%B.PACKAGES to ADD
%The next commands are for latex packages which we sometimes use. %
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%COMMENT: The next 2 software packages are only for presentations. %
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%C. PAGE LAYOUT.
%The following commands are not for presentations!
%These commands are for creating margins, text width, text length %and double spacing for papers.
%
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{10pt} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{10pt} %\setlength{\textwidth}{430pt}
%\textwidth 15cm
%\oddsidemargin .2cm \evensidemargin .2cm
%\textheight 20cm
%\topmargin -.3cm
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
%D.COLORS.
%These commands are for colors for papers and presentations. %Note that \rrr makes RED, %\bbb makes BLUE,
%\ppp makes PURPLE and \ggg makes GREEN. 
\definecolor{b}{rgb}{.1,.1,.7}
\definecolor{rr}{rgb}{.8,0,.3}
\definecolor{g}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{pp}{rgb}{.5,0,.7}
\definecolor{r}{rgb}{.6,0,.3} \definecolor{y}{rgb}{.9,.99,.9} \newcommand{\rrr}{\textcolor{rr}} \newcommand{\bbb}{\textcolor{b}} \newcommand{\ppp}{\textcolor{pp}} \renewcommand{\ggg}{\textcolor{g}} \newcommand{\grr}{\ggg} \newcommand{\bbl}{\bbb}
%E.ABBREVIATIONS.
%The next commands are abbreviations used frequently % especially in multi-variable calculus.
%
\newcommand{\vr}{{\ppp{\bf r}}} \newcommand{\va}{\ppp{\bf a}} \newcommand{\vi}{{\rrr{\bf i}}} \newcommand{\vj}{{\rrr{\bf j}}} \newcommand{\vk}{{\rrr{\bf k}}} \newcommand{\vu}{\rrr{\bf u}} \newcommand{\vb}{\bbb{\bf b}} \newcommand{\vv}{\bbl{\bf v}} \newcommand{\vn}{{\ppp{\bf n}}} \newcommand{\vw}{\ppp{\bf w}} \newcommand{\rR}{\rrr{\bf R}} \newcommand{\rA}{{\rrr{\bf A}}} \newcommand{\rrth}{{\bf \rR}^{\bf 3}} \newcommand{\rrtw}{{\bf \rR}^{\bf 2}} \renewcommand{\v}{\overset{\longrightarrow}}
%F.NEGATIVE SPACE
%The next 3 commands are for negative spacing and are %used frequently in presentations. \newcommand{\vsp}{\vspace{-.1cm}} \newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{-.2cm}} \newcommand{\vspa}{\vspace{-.3cm}}
%G. NUMBERED THEOREMS, DEFINITIONS,...
%These commands are for papers only.
%(for presentations, they need to be commented out).
%They create numbered theorems and other numbered objects like definitions % The ``section'' part produces numbering by section.
%If you remove that part, then the section number %where the "theorem" is located will not appear
%in the numbering of the statement of the "theorem". %
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} %\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
%G'.
%Some commands mostly for presentations. %
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture} \newtheorem{history}{\large History} \newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question} \newtheorem{Case}{Case} \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
%H.SHORTHANDS \def and \newcommand.
%The command \def is used create abbreviations for
%frequently used symbols like the math symbol for capital R
%that we use to denote the real numbers or the Greek letter theta.
%
%For longer abbreviations or commands, we usually use the command %\newcommand. For example, instead of typing \end{document}
%I usually type \ed instead.
%
%It may not be a good idea to use too many of
%these abbreviations if someone else (a coauthor) is
%reading your tex document, they may not understand.
%
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\rth{\mathbb{R}^3}
\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{enumerate}} \newcommand{\bit}{\begin{itemize}} \newcommand{\een}{\end{enumerate}} \newcommand{\eit}{\end{itemize}} \newcommand{\ed}{\end{document}}
%X. GRAY shaded BLOCKS in presentations.
%The next 2 commands are for creating gray shaded blocks in presentations. \newcommand{\bblock}{\begin{block}} \newcommand{\eblock}{\end{block}}



\begin{document}

\begin{exampleblock}{Example (This is a very popular midterm exam problem)}
Find an \textcolor{b}{equation of the plane} which contains the points \\
$P(-1,2,1)$, $Q(1,-2,1)$, and $R(1,1,-1)$.
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}{Solution:}
\bf\Large Method 1
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see this error message: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try wrapping things in `\begin{frame}` ... `\end{frame}`.

Comment: @steph Sorry to bother you, but now that your questions have received answers, please  consider accepting those that you consider solved your problems. This can be done by clicking the checkmark to the left of the chosen answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the [beamer package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer)

> In beamer, a presentation consists of a series of frames.

So, you need `\begin{frame}{<frametitle>}` and `\end{frame}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A nice slide}
\begin{exampleblock}{This is an example}
Some text
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{block}{Solution:}  
\begin{itemize}  
\item A 
\item B 
\item C    
\end{itemize} 
\end{block}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I did not realize that was necessary